# s3 file upload - not working for video - React/Meteor - aws-sdk

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, meteor, aws-sdk

I am having issue uploading mp4 files to my s3 bucket in my react/meteor project. It works for the other type of files (mp3, images) but not for video. I don't get any error but when I try to read the file that was uploaded it doesn't work.

here is my client code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { types } from "../../../utils/constants/types";

const FileUpload = ({ fileType, type, typeId, subtype, setFileName }) => {
  const handleUpload = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const fileExtension = file.type;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
      Meteor.call(
        "uploadFile",
        fileExtension,
        reader.result,
        type,
        typeId,
        (err, result) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            setFileName(result);
          }
        }
      );
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input name="Uploader" onChange={handleUpload} type="file" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

and there is my meteor method on the server side:

```
Meteor.methods({
  uploadFile: async function (fileType, data, type, typeId) {
    let extension;
    let contentType = fileType;

      if (fileType.includes("jpeg") || fileType.includes("jpg")) {
        extension = "jpg";
      } else if (fileType.includes("png")) {
        extension = "png";
      } else if (fileType.includes("mp4")) {
        extension = "mp4";
      } else if (fileType.includes("audio/mpeg")) {
        contentType = "video/mp4";
        extension = "mp3";
      } else if (fileType.includes("pdf")) {
        extension = "pdf";
      } else {
        throw new Meteor.Error("format-error", "Only authorized format");
      }

      const random = Random.id();
      const key = `random.${extension}`;

      const buf =
        extension !== "mp4"
          ? Buffer.from(data.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""), "base64")
          : data;

      const config = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: key,
        Body: buf,
        ContentType: contentType,
        ACL: "public-read",
      };

      if (extension !== "mp4") {
        config.ContentEncoding = "base64";
      }
      const uploadResult = await s3.upload(config).promise();
      return uploadResult.Location;

  },
});
```

I think it may come from the reader not managing properly video files but I'm a bit lost there. Any input would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is the file not there or is the content bad?

Comment: content is apparently bad. It's supposed to be a 4 seconds video and I get nothing (0 seconds)

Comment: Are you sure the `onload` callback is triggered when you think it is? What happens if you just manually call `uploadFile` after loading the data?

Comment: as mentionned the code works for images and mp3, just the mp4 don't work somehow.

Comment: @Exelian also I can get the file using wget and its size is normal but can play it locally.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to ask, since I see your code is pretty complicated. Why do you upload files via your server?

I think it is more efficient to push files from the client straight to S3. Please have a look at this package that I am maintaining if you are interested to see the concept (https://github.com/activitree/s3up-meta). It is a re-write of an older hard-tested package from years back. Uploads are signed by the Meteor server but uploaded by the client. You don't want to keep sockets/fibers busy with file uploads while also a lot of data is coming in for each upload (data about the status of upload). You would want to have that all on the user/client side.

Another thing to note is the importance of setting the `AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload` in your bucket/Management/Lifecycle. This is where your S3 size may grow without control.

Finally, when I upload video, I just upload the file (received from the input type file). It looks like this:

```
video: File
   lastModified: 1573722339000
   lastModifiedDate: Thu Nov 14 2019 13:05:39 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time) {}
   name: "IMG_7847.MOV"
   size: 20719894
   type: "video/quicktime"
   webkitRelativePath: ""
```

I do use other helpers to determine the file (and limit the time length of the permitted uploads) and file type.

You could monitor the errors on your server side as you upload or/and activate CloudWatch on S3 side to see where things are failing.

Comment: I'll check your solution, I like the idea to upload directly from client with just getting an authorization from the server.